# check if string and int entered in constructor

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to learn java and I am having some issues with my code. I am trying to use an if statement to check there has been any input into the constructor. If the email String  **and** the membership number have been entered,  the check logged in status method should return that the user is logged in. other wise it should return they are not logged in.

```
public class Member
{
    // varibales declaration 
    private String email;  
    private int membershipNumber; 
    private boolean loggedInStatus; 

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Member
     */
    public Member(String memberEmail, int newMembershipNumber )
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        email = memberEmail;
        membershipNumber = newMembershipNumber;
    }

    //loggedInStatus method
    public void setloggedInStatus() 
    { 
        if ( email == email && membershipNumber == membershipNumber ) {

            System.out.println("you are logged in ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("you are not logged in");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to check if they are not empty ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with ``email == email`` and ``membershipNumber == membershipNumber`` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there hasn't been any input, both variables will contain default values (`null` for a String, `0` for an integer.

You could check that:

```
public void setloggedInStatus() {
    if (email != null && membershipNumber != 0) {
        System.out.println("you are logged in ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("you are not logged in");
    }
}
```

But in your case it's not possible to call the constructor without an argument for `email` and `membershipNumber`. Both will always have a value, their values just might be `null` and `0`. You have to decide if that makes sense in your case and if an expression like `if (email != null && membershipNumber != 0)` is enough to check both values for validation.